# How to write basic macro to compare two columns for a difference within .50?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that compares the differences between values in columns B and C. I'd like the macro to compare the two columns (B & C) and find depths that are within +/- .50 of each other, and I'd like to keep track of the sample # (column A) that corresponds to the sample depth that is within +/- .50 of the test depth, and then to find the difference between the sample depth and test depth. For example, the following images are before and after what I'd like the macro to look like:

Before:

[image: img1]

After:

[image: img2]

Comment: You say you are trying to write a macro.  Please post your code so that we can help.

Comment: I can't figure out how you're getting from your before to after, specifically with column E and F - can you please elaborate?

Comment: It sounds like you're just trying to check whether the values in column B and C are within .5 of each other. If so, why do you need a macro instead of just using a formula?

Comment: I'm open to use a formula if it's possible, but I'm not sure how to do that. I'm comparing all the values in Column C with all the values in Column B to see if any of them are within +/- .5, and if any of them are within +/- .5, they would show up in columns E and F, showing the pair that is within +/- .5, and column G shows the sample number that the matched depth comes from, followed by the difference between the two values.The possible depth values that might meet the +/- .5 criteria might not necessarily be in the same row in B and C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go.  nested loop for the read, iterator to count the output row.  May need some customization, but this is the core of it.

```
Sub foo()

    Dim itr As Integer
    itr = 2

    For Each sd In Range("B:B")

        If sd.Value = "" Then Exit For
        If IsNumeric(sd.Value) Then

        For Each td In Range("C:C")

            If td.Value = "" Then Exit For
            If IsNumeric(td.Value) Then

                If Abs(sd.Value - td.Value) < 0.5 Then

                    Cells(itr, 5) = sd.Value
                    Cells(itr, 6) = td.Value

                    Cells(itr, 8) = sd.Value - td.Value

                    itr = itr + 1
                End If

            End If
        Next td


        End If
    Next sd
End Sub
```